# BinaryFormatter not overwriting/updating serialized item

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization

I tried using the binaryFormatter as a method of saving and loading all types of data in my game (accounts, score) which are structs containing fields and/or lists. The thing is that it doesn't seem to overwrite or update data in a file once it's serialized.

For example, I create a List containing two PlayerAccounts and serialize it. To be extra careful for testing I deserialize into a new List of Playeraccounts. The first time the data is serialized just fine, but when I add another account to the list and serialize it again, the changes don't seem to be noticed. Maybe I have searched for the issue but it seems I missed out on something.

Because there is a lot of code involved i just created a simple save and load then try to overwrite using a List of ints which does the same thing so I guess it serves as a subsitute.

here's the main code:

```
string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/mEs.binary";

FileStream fsWrite = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

List<int> input = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

bf.Serialize(fsWrite, input);

fsWrite.Close();

FileStream fsRead = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

List<int> output = (List<int>)bf.Deserialize(fsRead);

fsRead.Close();

print("first entry:");

foreach (int entry in output)
{
    print(entry);
    //prints 1 to 4
}

input = output;

input.Add(5);

fsWrite = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);

bf.Serialize(fsWrite, input); //add the updated List of ints

fsWrite.Close();

fsRead = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

output = (List<int>)bf.Deserialize(fsRead);

print("second entry:");

foreach (int entry in output)
{
    print(entry);
    //prints 1 to 4 again (instead of 1 to 5)
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you expect from `, FileMode.Append` (without such explanation looks like simple copy-paste mistake)

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov seems I just misunderstood the functionality of "FileMode.Append" in this case. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alexei Levenkov mentioned, the problem is using FileMode.Append when writing the stream. It appends the new list (1..5) to the end of the file.

You could test this if you try to read a second list from the file (use `output = (List<int>)bf.Deserialize(fsRead);` twice in your example). The first read will create a list of 1..4, the second read a list of 1..5.

Use FileMore.Create instead of FileMode.Append to override the (old) existing file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, obviously there was just a clear misunderstanding of "FileMode.Append" because I only used it when reading and writing string data and never had a problem with it up to this point.